# How to solve reciprocal linear function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I was doing my homework and the last question was said to be a trickier one and if you could figure it out, then do it. It's bugging me as I want to understand how to do it. The question is as is:

How could you put this equation, $y=\frac{x+3}{x+1}$ in the standard $y=a\text{f}(k(x-d))+c$ form?

Comment: Is that $\frac{x+3}{x+1}$? And what is the base function we're supposed to transform to/from?

Comment: Note that $a,f,k$ are redundant in your standard form.

Comment: Yes its that, and the base function is y = 1/x, the hyperbola's

Comment: What do you mean, "the base function is $y=1/x$"? What are the meanings of $a,f,k$ in your $y=af(k(x-d)+c$ form, and why aren't the parentheses balanced? If $a,f,k$ are just numbers, then $y=(x+3)/(x+1)$ is a hyperbola but the other is a line, so you can't write the one in the form of the other. The question is very unclear.

Comment: a, k, c, d are numbers. f is a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't express the function in that form.  You can write $y=1+\frac 2{x+1}$, but your standard form is a straight line and this equation is a hyperbola.  Maybe your $f$ is a function, not an integer.  In that case you can write it in your standard form-$c=1, a=1, k=2, d=-1, f(z)=\frac 1z$

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as follows:

$y=af(k(x-d))+c$
Where:

$c=1,a=2,k=1,d=−1,f(x)=\frac1x$

So here are two possibilities:

$y=2f(x+1)+1$

or

$y=\frac{2}{x+1}+1$

Feel free to verify using wolfram alpha : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1